# Azure Static Web App JWT token generation

Tags: node.js, azure, jwt, azure-functions, token

I've got an Azure static web app (with Azure functions as API). When the user log's in we generate a token with the following code:

```
function generateToken(user: User): string{
  const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

  const tokenData = {
    userId: user.id,
  }

  const tokenOptions = {
    expireIn: "2 days"
  }

  const token = jwt.sign(tokenData, process.env.SECRET_KEY, tokenOptions});
  return token;
}
```

However, after calling a different function, the jwt.verify throws an invalid signature error.

```
try{
      const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
      jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {algorithms: ['HS256']});
    }catch(tokenError){
      context.res = {
        status: 401,
        body: `tokenError: ${tokenError}\n
        token: ${req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1]}\n
        decode: ${JSON.stringify(jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1]))}\n
        `
      };
      return;
    }
```

The code works perfectly locally, but after deploying it the payload changes from:

```
{"userId":2,"iat":1701863111,"exp":1702035911}
```

to

```
{"nbf":1701863176,"exp":1701863476,"iat":1701863176,"iss":"https://5de6fdb8-19cf-4d6e-9fd0-50a67c40ca59.scm.azurewebsites.net","aud":"https://5de6fdb8-19cf-4d6e-9fd0-50a67c40ca59.azurewebsites.net/azurefunctions"}
```

Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

I've tried several settings change for the generateToken, also checked that the enviroment variable is accessed by azure function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with generating the JWT token and configuring the token options .The payload of the JWT token is changing after deploying to Azure is because the audience claims are being added to the token by Azure due  done for security reasons, as it helps to ensure that the token is only valid for the Azure Static Web App.

- I used the "Not Before" claim (`nbf`) in the token generated by Azure.

```java
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function generateToken(user) {
  const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

  const tokenData = {
    userId: user.id,
  };

  const tokenOptions = {
    expiresIn: "2 days",
    notBefore: 0
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(tokenData, secretKey, tokenOptions);
  return token;
}


function verifyToken(req, context) {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { algorithms: ['HS256'] });
    console.log("Decoded Token:", decodedToken);
    // Your logic with the decoded token
  } catch (tokenError) {
    context.res = {
      status: 401,
      body: `tokenError: ${tokenError}\n
        token: ${req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1]}\n
        decode: ${JSON.stringify(jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1]))}\n
        `,
    };
    return;
  }
}

// Usage example
const user = { id: 2 };
const generatedToken = generateToken(user);
console.log("Generated Token:", generatedToken);


const request = {
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${generatedToken}`,
  },
};

verifyToken(request, { res: {} });
```

**Local:**

[image]

[image]

- I followed this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=vanilla-javascript) to add an API to Azure Static Web Apps with Azure [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own).

[image]